# Is Zeebe good for running long workflows and backward compatibility?

Tags: camunda, zeebe

I was trying to create a workflow with user-task where usertask can take months to complete.
Now consider I deployed version 1 of the workflow and even few instances of same started.

Due to some changes in process I want to change the workflow which will be version 2.

Is it possible to achieve backward compatibility[I want my version 2 changes to reflect on already running workflow].

Only new instances are picking new changes and if I make any change in task definition type that will make my previous running workflow useless.